# Wordpress autologin link only works when clicked twice or reloaded

Tags: php, wordpress, autologin

I have a Wordpress site and I have setup an autologin PHP script that checks for a KEY value in the URL which corresponds to a user in a table and then logs that user into the site. I have this because I have a user who requested to be able to login to the site by just clicking a link and not having to enter in a username and password each time.

I have gotten it to work, the weird thing is though it only works some of the time. When a user clicks the link it takes them to a landing page for that user.

The autologin link looks like this: https://mywebsite.org/home/autologin.php?key=54321

Sometimes when the link is clicked it just sits at that url, other times it properly logs in and redirects to the landing page url which is: https://mywebsite.org/library-portal-landing-page/

When the link just stalls and sits on the autologin URL the page will redirect and load if the autologin link is reloaded and I am not sure why it needs reloaded sometimes and other times it just works.

Here is my autologin.php PHP script:

```
<?php
require_once("wp-load.php");
global $wpdb;

// Check if user is already logged in, redirect to account if true
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {

// Check if the key is set and not emtpy
if(isset($_GET['key']) && !empty($_GET['key'])){

    // Sanitize the received key to prevent SQL Injections
    $received_key = sanitize_text_field($_GET['key']);
   
    // Find the username from the database using the received key
    $get_username = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT avatar FROM wp_autologin WHERE random_key = %s", $received_key ) );
   
    // Check if query returned a result, throw an error if false
    if(!empty($get_username)){
   
        // Get user info from username then save it to a variable
        $user = get_user_by('login', $get_username );
       
        // Get the user id then set the login cookies to the browser
        wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID);
       
        // To make sure that the login cookies are already set, we double check.
        foreach($_COOKIE as $name => $value) {
           
            // Find the cookie with prefix starting with "wordpress_logged_in_"
            if(substr($name, 0, strlen('wordpress_logged_in_')) == 'wordpress_logged_in_') {
           
                // Redirect to account page if the login cookie is already set.
                wp_redirect( home_url('/library-portal-landing-page/') );
               
            } else {
           
                // If NOT set, we loop the URL until login cookie gets set to the browser
                wp_redirect( home_url('/home/autologin/?key=' . $received_key) );
                   
            }
        }
       
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid Authentication Key';
    }
} else {
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
}

} else {
wp_redirect( home_url('/library-portal-landing-page/') );
exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by adding a javascript redirect to run after a few seconds which did the trick, I added this after the end of the PHP file:

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.href = "https://mywebsite.org/library-portal-landing-page/";
        }, 2000);
</script>
```